# SELECT INTO query

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have to write an `SELECT INTO T-SQL` script for a table which has columns `acc_number`, `history_number` and `note`.

How do i facilitate an incremental value of `history_number` for each record being inserted via `SELECT INTO.`

Note, that the value for `history_number` comes off as a different value for each `account` from a different table.

Comment: Does the table already exist? Are you using a temp table?

Comment: The table already exists, i am populating it with values from a different database. It is not an identity column.

Comment: You need to increment based on the ID, then restart the increment for each new ID?  Use `Rank()`.  If that doesnt describe what you are trying to do add some sample input/output please.

Comment: I need to increment based on the account number, for example : If there are 2 entries for the same account then the second entry will have +1 value for the history_number.

Comment: see new edit and working fiddle below.

Comment: It might be a good idea to illustrate your problem with an example (what the source looks like, what the corresponding result should be).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT history_number = IDENTITY(INT,1,1),
    ... etc...
INTO NewTable
FROM ExistingTable
WHERE ...
```

You could use ROW_NUMBER instead of identity i.e. ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY )

Comment: Hi Jason, it is not an identity column. It's an integer value coming off from another table and the values picked up for increment are different for each account.[there are several records for each account being picked up so i need to pick up the history_number value for an account and then keep incrementing it for every record it has.]

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT acc_number
    ,o.historynumber
    ,note
    ,o.historynumber+DENSE_RANK() OVER (Partition By acc_number ORDER BY Note) AS NewHistoryNumber 
                                                              --Or some other order by probably a timestamp...
FROM Table t
INNER JOIN OtherTable o
ON ....
```

[Working Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/58a4e/11/0)

The will give you an incremented count starting from history number for each accnum.  I suggest you use a better order by in the rank but there was not enough info in the question.

This answer to this question may help you as well
[Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12739208/how-to-use-rank-in-sql-server)

Answer (score 0):

Suppose your SELECT statement is like this

```
SELECT  acc_number,
        history_number,
        note
FROM    [Table]
```

Try this Query as below.

```
SELECT  ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY acc_number) ID,
        acc_number,
        history_number,
        note    
INTO    [NewTable]
FROM    [Table]
```