# Vb.net Student Ranking

Tags: sql, vb.net, sql-server-2012

I need some assistance, I'm working on a school project and having issue ranking the students according to the school specification. For example, in a class of 10 pupils, each pupil's score is `80,70,70,60,60,50,40,30,30,20` respectively. When using `Rank` in SQL Server to get each pupil's rank, it will output this

```
Score   Rank
------------
80      1
70      2
70      3
60      4
60      5
50      6
40      7
30      8
30      9
20      10
```

What I want is for pupils with the same score to have the same ranking. It should look like this

```
Score   Rank
------------
80      1
70      2
70      2        
60      4
60      5
50      6
30      7
30      7
30      7
20      10
```

I am using vb.net 2013 and Sql server 2012, and I'm displaying the data from the database to a DataGridView.

[image]

Comment: Where are you running into issues so far? Can you show us your current code / script?

Comment: SQL is the generic query language for most all DBs. which db specifically are you using ( some have this built in). Your question could merit from some line breaks, punctuation...and code showing what you tried.

Comment: "SELECT
MarkEntry.[Total Score] AS Total,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY sum(markentry.TotalScore) Desc) AS Position, FROM MarkEntry, All the data is coming from database to datagridview and the result was table 1 above and i want it to be like table 2

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use RANK() in SQL Server](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12739208/how-to-use-rank-in-sql-server)

Comment: I cant solve it using rank in sql server, pls try solve for me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
DECLARE @Table TABLE(
    ContenderNum INT,
    totals FLOAT
)

INSERT INTO @Table SELECT 1, 196
INSERT INTO @Table SELECT 2, 181
INSERT INTO @Table SELECT 3, 192
INSERT INTO @Table SELECT 4, 181
INSERT INTO @Table SELECT 5, 179

SELECT contendernum,totals, 
    RANK() OVER (ORDER BY totals DESC) AS xRank,
    DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY totals DESC) AS xRank
FROM 
( 
    SELECT ContenderNum ,totals 
    FROM @Table
) AS a
ORDER BY 1
```

It solve it, I was using SQL `Row_Number`.